# Why doesn't instanceof pattern matching work with else if in this particular case?

Tags: java, language-lawyer, java-17

The following snippet does not compile on javac, version 17 (Temurin)

```
class Instanceof {
    static void doesNotWork(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            throw new Error();
        } else if (!(o instanceof String s)) {
            throw new Error();
        }   
        System.out.println(s); // error here
    }
}
```

It generates this error: cannot find symbol

```
cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable s
location: class Instanceof
```

However, the following (in my opinion) equivalent variations work:
With an explicit else block:

```
static void doesWork(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        throw new Error();
    } else if (!(o instanceof String s)) {
        throw new Error();
    } else {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Or without an else:

```
static void doesWork(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        throw new Error();
    }
    if (!(o instanceof String s)) {
        throw new Error();
    }
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Or with a single if:

```
static void doesWork(Object o) {
    if (o == null || !(o instanceof String s)) {
        throw new Error();
    }
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Is this a bug in javac?
If yes, should I report this, but where exactly?

Comment: @RealSkeptic See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/pattern-matching.html

Comment: The relevant section is [§6.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3.1) - the error indicates that `javac` thinks variable `s` is not in scope here, given that the error is "s? What s?". It's like a `javac` bug, but I haven't  yet found the exact chapter and verse where `javac` breaks spec here.

Comment: To my untrained eye, it does seem to be an issue. I can't see any logical reason why the examples you've showed would work, but that one wouldn't. You can report a bug here: https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/

Comment: I *suspect* this is a difference in the reachability of if-then-else vs if-then, depending on the body of the clauses.

Comment: Looks scope related, like `s` being available in the `if` scope only… Would be weird if that was the reason… Could be a bug or intentional and your use case is not covered (since you want to print `s` in the outer scope while it is declared in an inner scope). The `else` extends the scope, which explains why that option does work.

Comment: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/394 includes an example that is very similar so I think it is a bug. Please report it (link in other comment above)!

Comment: Going by the example (under _"The flow scoping analysis for pattern variables is sensitive to the notion of whether a statement can complete normally."_) seems to suggest both should be equivalent, so I guess it's a bug, but maybe the null check is throwing this flow analysis off here.

Comment: I would have expected that `s` has a possible scope inside the if's `( )` and inside the `{ }`; comparable to _try-with-resources_. Anything else is bad style imho.

Comment: @JoopEggen Kind of agree, but you have to remember that `s` is really just `o` with type-narrowing, and `o` is already in-scope. The point of pattern matching is to make the compiler able to perform some of the same inferences that humans can. A human can infer that `o` is a String after those if-statements, because it would have thrown an exception if it weren't.

Comment: @Michael right, but `if (... && !(o instanceof String s) && ...) { ... } ... s` becomes slightly dubious.  I hope a more strict ruling will come soon.

Comment: Works with Eclipse. As a side note, the `null` check is obsolete here…

Comment: @JonSkeet not just reachability issue, please check my example in the answers. It seems that this is probably an issue of how the compiler evaluates and transforms the code.

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos: No, your example seems to actually point to reachability being important, just as I was suggesting...

Comment: The second example of [JLS § 6.3.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3.2) looks very much like the abovementioned examples. *Looks* to me it's related to how exactly `if`, `else if` and `else` work. Kinda what k314159 says in their answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `doesNotWork` case is equivalent to this:

```
static void doesNotWork(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        throw new Error();
    } else {
        if (!(o instanceof String s)) {
            throw new Error();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(s); // error here
}
```

This makes it more obvious that `String s` is inside a block bounded by curly brackets and is therefore out of scope in the same way that this doesn't work either:

```
static void doesNotWork(Object o) {
    {
        if (!(o instanceof String s)) {
            throw new Error();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(s); // error here
}
```

In the case where it does work, with the println inside the else, it's equivalent to this:

```
if (o == null) {
    throw new Error();
} else {
    if (!(o instanceof String s)) {
        throw new Error();
    } else {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Which shows the println being in scope.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable guess, but if it were simple a matter of scope then I'd be surprised that Eclipse's compiler wouldn't work the same way.

Comment: Now, the question is, does being equivalent to a block allow treating the code as if being inside a block, even if it’s not? `javac` doesn’t seem to be consistent. E.g. if I change the code to `do if(!(o instanceof String s)) throw new Error(); while(false); System.out.println(s);` it compiles the code (as Eclipse does), despite being equivalent to `do { if(!(o instanceof String s)) throw new Error(); } while(false); System.out.println(s);` which both compilers reject.

Comment: I can use the same '_this_ is essentially equivalent to _that_' tactic to say that `int a = 5; System.out.println(a);` is equivalent to `{int a = 5;} {System.out.println(a);}` and thus should not compile: Braces define scope, therefore imagining them here isn't a valid approach. I think this indeed explains what happens, but I'd say this means either the JLS is bugged or javac is.

Comment: @rzwitserloot note that I intentionally searched for an example with a control flow construct, rather than putting `{ }` around an arbitrary statement, to show that even then, the behavior is not consistent. If the inner statement of a `do … while` loop is only treated as a block if written as a block and, in fact, the entire loop is treated as a single statement when no block is present, this should apply to the `else` clause as well. Like Eclipse does, consistently.

Answer (score 7):

The relevant bug ticket has been created in the OpenJdk Jira. It is marked as reproduceable so most probably will be handled as bug, and fixed.

Here is the [aforementioned ticket](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8287884) so we can trace the progress.

**Edit**: Seems that this issue is going to affect JDK 20 as well. Resolution is going to take some time.

Comment: I have decided to accept the other answer as the mentioned issue currently also indicates that it is because of the specific way if else is done.